# 'X' clinics - what should replace 'X'? The problem or the solution?

Tags: word-usage

What comes at the place of 'X' is really fun to learn -

> a) **Obesity** clinic - the clinic where **obesity** is treated. After some time, obesity is *gone.* 
>  b)  **Diabetes** clinic - the clinic where **diabetes** is treated. After some time diabetes is *gone.* **BUT...** 
>  c) **Fertility** clinic - the clinic where <del>fertility</del> **infertility** is treated. After some time, <del>fertility</del> infertility is *gone*.
>
> In *(a)* and *(b)*, the **problem** replaced the 'X' whereas in *(c)*, the **solution** replaced the 'X'.

In this way, what should replace 'X' if the clinic is to **remove hair from head** and make a person bald. These days, *bald is beautiful!* It's fashion and many prefer it.

> **Hair** clinic - the clinic where **hair** is treated. After some time, *hair* is gone! **Really?**

**Certainly not;** a *hair clinic* is where the problems of *hair* are treated. In fact, **if you suffer from baldness, you are likely to visit *hair clinic.***

On the other hand, if you use *baldness*, it further creates ambiguity.

> **Baldness clinic** - the clinic where **baldness** is treated. After some time, baldness is *gone.* But I **want baldness.**

Comment: dear @downvoter, comment please! If it's easy for you, enlighten me.

Comment: Not the one who downvoted but these terms are not standard but general. For example, some people say "infertility clinic" and "hair loss clinic" in place of "fertility clinic" and "hair clinic". I don't know much but I don't think there exists an answer to this question.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija if you think a little bit, the question still stands even with your examples. The question is about the same structure but different words sometimes meaning same other times completely opposite.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more accurate to say these places "deal with the issue of", which is more neutral.
An obesity clinic deals with the issue of obesity by reducing it.
A health clinic deals with the issue of health by increasing it.

What is chosen is either easier to say or more recognizable. In addition, most people would realize that whatever is being "dealt with" by the clinic would be whatever is harder for an individual to deal with by themselves. If you see a "baldness clinic", you can be certain they want to solve your baldness. If you *wanted* your hair gone you could shave it off yourself or go to a barbershop.

So for example:
People go to an obesity clinic to reduce their obesity because becoming obese is easier than getting skinny.
People would go to a skinny clinic to reduce their obesity because becoming obese is easier than getting skinny.

Alternatively, if you're one of those rare people who wants to go in the other direction, there's usually another place already set up for you.

- If you wanted to be infertile, instead of a fertility clinic you would go to a doctor (for an operation).
- If you wanted to be bald, instead of a hair clinic you would go to a barbershop.
- If you wanted to be obese, instead of an obesity clinic you would go to McDonalds.

Essentially - it's arbitrary whether they use the "problem" or the "solution", because most people will understand what is meant.